# Flutter FutureBuilder shows data then disappears when calling Rest API (Backend Laravel)

Tags: laravel, api, flutter, dart

I'm running a flutter application with a laravel backend and I have some issues.

The problem is the FutureBuilder show data then it disappears;  Sometimes length==4 then it turns to 0 and shows 'no data' in Scaffold

The same when I refresh the code.

PS: I'm running laravel on localhost and using a real device to test.

Environment: Android Studio, Windows 10, Real device

Laravel project: https://github.com/brakenseddik/blog_api_laravel

Flutter project: https://github.com/brakenseddik/blog_api_flutter
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

```
class Repository {
  String _baseUrl = 'http://192.168.1.2:8000/api';
  httpGet(String api) async {
    return await http.get(_baseUrl + '/' + api);
  }
}
```

here the homepage source code

```
 import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:blog_api/models/post_model.dart';
import 'package:blog_api/services/post_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  PostService _postService = PostService();
  List<PostModel> _list = List<PostModel>();

  Future<List<PostModel>> _getPosts() async {
    var result = await _postService.getAllPosts();
    _list = [];
    if (result != null) {
      var blogPosts = json.decode(result.body);
      blogPosts.forEach((post) {
        PostModel model = PostModel();
        setState(() {
          model.title = post['title'];
          model.details = post['details'];
          model.imageUrl = post['featured_image_url'];
          _list.add(model);
        });
      });
    }

    return _list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Blog App'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getPosts(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PostModel>> snapshot) {
            print('length of list ${_list.length}');
            _list = snapshot.data;
            if (_list.length == 0) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('No data'),
              );
            } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Image.network(
                                snapshot.data[index].imageUrl,
                                height: 150,
                                //  width: double.maxFinite,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                snapshot.data[index].title,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                snapshot.data[index].details.substring(0, 25),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

And the PostService

```
import 'package:blog_api/repository/repository.dart';

class PostService {
  Repository _repository;
  PostService() {
    _repository = Repository();
  }
  getAllPosts() async {
    return await _repository.httpGet('get-posts');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're calling `setState` in `_getPosts()`. This will rebuild everything and never give the response to the `FutureBuilder`. Just run the code without `setState`:

```
blogPosts.forEach((post) {
PostModel model = PostModel();
model.title = post['title'];
model.details = post['details'];
model.imageUrl = post['featured_image_url'];
_list.add(model);
```

`FutureBuilder` will initially call its builder with a snapshot that doesn't have any data yet. Once it receives the data, it will call its builder again. Because of this, `if (_list.length == 0)` will result in a NPE, since `_list` is null.

I would try changing the order of the if statements:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  );
} else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
  return Center(
    child: Text('No data'),
  );
} else {
  return ListView.builder( 
  //...
}
```

Comment: Yes I tested the API with POSTMAN and it works fine

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<PostModel>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<PostModel>>#52aac):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

Comment: I saw it was calling setState in `getPosts`, which it shouldn't. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
future: _getPosts(),
```

Don't do that. This means every time `build` is called, you are querying your API *again*.

Create a variable of type `Future<List<PostModel>>`, assign `_getPosts()` to it **once** and then use that variable with your FutureBuilder.

Comment: But this one will do the same, Could you clarify more!

Comment: Well, obviously you need to follow the advice of the other post as well.